# Photon Realtime: PluginHost.HttpRequest what does parameter 'Async' mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

*Async: a flag that indicates if the normal processing of the room logic should be interrupted until the response is received or not. This should be set to false if the room logic depends on the HTTP response.*

If I set Async = true, would HTTP request run in a new thread?
If yes, How many new threads does Photon allow?

Answer (score 1):

there

> If I set Async = true, would HTTP request run in a new thread? If yes, How many new threads does Photon allow?

we use a thread pool. Just Default Thread pool which available for application. Request execution has a few stages, each of them might be executed on new thread pool thread or some threads can be reused.

This is not really important. The main thing is that you will get a call to your callback in a thread-safe manner. It may happen in the same thread or in a new thread.

best,

Photonians

Comment: To learn more about threading Photon, read this [section in Photon Server FAQ](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/onpremise/current/reference/faq#threading)
and this [section in Photon Realtime Plugins FAQ](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/onpremise/current/plugins/plugins-faq#threading)